# Session variable doesn't change when it's incremented

Tags: python, session, flask, facebook-messenger-bot

I have a messenger bot that asks questions in a sequential way. To keep track of the questions I'm using a counter which is a session variable.But when I increment the session[counter'] it doesn't change.

Here's the logic. Even if this code works, I'm not sure why when I implement the same logic for my bot, it doesn't work.

```
question_dict = {
        'Locq0':[{'question':"Some question 0",'options':(["Continue","@continue"])}],
        'Locq1':[{'question':"Some question 1",'options':(["Continue","@continue"])}],
        'Locq2':[{'question':"Some question 2",'options':(["Continue","@continue"])}],
}

def main():
  session['counter'] = 0
  if user_payload == "@continue":
      increment()

def increment(): 
    if session['counter'] <= len(question_dict):
       session['counter'] += 1
       quiz(session['counter'])

def quiz(counter):
    question = question_dict['Locq{}'.format(counter)][0]['question']
    option   = question_dict['Locq{}'.format(counter)][0]['options']
    # display the question and option
    print(question)
    print(option)
```

Back to the bot. When the user uses the bot for the first time, a session variable is created `session['counter']` and it's initialized to 0. Then the bot starts asking questions, to move to the next question it should increment  `session['counter'] +=1`. But that doesn't happen, `session['counter']` is always 0, even though the increment() function is called.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there a proper way to do it? This app is served using Flask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because when the main method is called, it is throwing an error. try initializing the dictionary first and then increment it.
the following code throws an error

```
def main():
  session['counter'] = 0
  if user_payload == "@continue":
      increment()
```

try the following code

```
 def main():
      session = {'counter':0}
      if user_payload == "@continue":
          increment()
```

Comment: Thanks! But, that's not the problem.It works fine when I use the same logic in a web app having forms. @Kalyan Reddy

Comment: then, may be you are updating session's counter to 0 again somewhere in the code. try changing the session dictionary as a global dictionary and let me know

Comment: session is a flask dict and counter is a session variable. I started using sessions because a multiprocress server can't keep track of globals. You can follow that question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45795977/python3-incrementing-a-global-variable-causes-bot-to-randomize-responses-when @Kalyan Reddy

Comment: can you just try printing session variable for each function, when I am trying, i am getting an error that session variable is not defined may be its because of the scope of the session variable

Comment: as you said "you are updating session's counter to 0 again somewhere in the code" that happens to be true. That part of the code shouldn't have executed, but it does. I'll try to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: welcome, mark this question as completed if your query is answered